# How to return translatable text in render array?

Tags: 8

I'm having a hard time returning translated text as a render array. I have a custom block plugin that will return a message if there's a specific kind of error:

```
  return [
    'message' => [
      'message' => $this->t('Courses for selected term have not been imported.'),
      '#prefix' => '<p>',
      '#suffix' => '</p>',
    ],
  ];
```

This doesn't work, it produces an error that 'message' is not a valid render array key.

What am I doing wrong here? `$this->t()` returns an instance of `\Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup` which I thought would be appropriate to return, but I think I'm not creating the render array properly.

Comment: You can put a translatable text in a render array, but you don't have a render array because it doesn't contain at least one render element, of which the simplest would be #markup as @IvanJaros suggested.

Comment: additionally: t returns translatable markup object and markup is renderable so you can just return t(), if you don't need the <p>s

Comment: But I do need the `<p>` tags. I can put the translated text as the value to '#markup' but I'm not sure that's correct. Would the cache metadata bubble up properly?

Comment: what cache metadata? a translatable string doesn't have that.

Comment: Hmm I guess I assumed it needed to set a cache context that indicated it depended on user language? I also was a bit confused because I thought anything that goes into #markup is meant to be just HTML, not something that's itself renderable.

Comment: t() returns TranslatableMarkup object which magically turns into a string when rendered

Comment: If you put a string in #markup it is converted to a markup object to mark it as safe and to protect the html tags from escaping. If there is already an instance of Markup or a subclass like TranslatableMarkup it is passed through. You don't need a cache context, because t() is translated to the interface language and this is a default context always set.

Comment: Thanks all. If someone wants to submit a full answer for this I will accept it so you get the credit!